# show uploaded image yii

Tags: yii

I am new to php and yii. I have a file field in my form to upload images. I use the following code to upload the image using file field.

Code in View:

```
<?php echo $form->fileField($model,'logo', array('class'=>'input-file')); ?>
    <img src="<?php 
        echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/protected/uploads/sitelogo/'.$savedvalues['varLogo']; 
    ?>" width="50" height="50" />
    <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'hiddenfile',
            array('value'=>$savedvalues['varLogo'])); ?>
```

code in controller:

```
$randnum = rand(0,100);
$home->varLogo = $randnum.$model->logo;
$file= Yii::app()->getBasePath().'/uploads/sitelogo/'.$randnum.$model->logo;
$model->logo->saveAs($file);
```

The images are uploading fine now. I have saved the uploaded images in `protected\uploads\` folder. I am trying to show the uploaded image in edit image section. But the image doesn't display. It Shows `failed to load the given url` in firebug.

How can i correct this issue?

Comment: so is this helped? ask your questions if something is unclear for you

Answer (score 2):

`protected` folder is protected for some reason - nobody can access it

if you want to access your pictures move them to `public` folder (or `public/uploaded`)

here is `.htaccess` content for `protected`

```
deny from all
```

`EDIT:`

of course you can put your files into protected folder(or make `uploaded` folder not accessible too) if you want some ACL for your users, and then check access, read and output file by your script(class)

in view:

```
<img src="<?php 
    echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/image.php?url=protected/uploads/sitelogo/'.$savedvalues['varLogo']; 
?>" width="50" height="50" />
```

in your controller or class:

```
if (Yii::app()->session['user_can_access_files']) {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    readfile($_GET['url']);
} else {
    Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
}
```

Comment: How can i save images in outer accessible folders?

Comment: Use `Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')` instead of `Yii::app()->getBasePath()`.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I'm a total yii noob, so take this w/ a grain of salt :)
I took a similar approach, but have user-specific folders & added a MIME type check. 
I upload files in a similar way, then view them with this in the view:

```
echo '<embed src="/tim_0.5/index.php/files/Getdatafile/' . $modelid . '" width=100% height=400>';
```

And from my controller I have:

```
public function actionGetdatafile($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        $imgpath = $model->user_id . '/' . $model->filename;
        $file=Yii::app()->getBasePath().'/datafiles/'.$imgpath;

        if (file_exists($file))
        {
            $img=getimagesize($file);
            header('Content-Type: '.$img['mime']);
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        } else {
        echo 'File not found!';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('binaryfile')); ?>:</b>

<?php  echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/upload/'.$data->fileName); ?>
<br />
```

filename is name of your file which you have stored in upload folder in root directory.

```
(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/upload/' point to your upload folder which is in your root directory
```

Hope it works....